Rails:bash: ./bin/rails: Permission denied while deploying in render
I have developed a rails project and pushed it on github to deploy it.But i am facing the following error while deploying the project in render..Although the project is running well locally..
For clarification::I have added render-build.sh file in my bin folder and also added render.yaml and pushed them also into the git repo..
I am facing below log errors called permission denied:
==> Build failed 

bash: ./bin/rails: Permission denied Bundled gems are installed into
/opt/render/project/.gems Gems in the groups 'development' and
'test' were not installed. Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies,
68 gems now installed.


you might want to add some lines from the log, especially those that come before the error

you also might want to include information from render.yaml file

I have solved the issue..Here on the start command i place of   "./bin/rails server" use "bundle exec rails server"
